# Github Actions variable $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY - Markdown not displaying

Tags: github-actions

I’ve created a very simple Github Actions workflow that is intended to display a step summary. My workflow is –

```
name: Show Markdown

on: [ pull_request ]
permissions: write-all
jobs:
  ShowMarkdown:
    runs-on: [ self-hosted ]
    steps:
      - name: Adding markdown
        if: always()
        run: |
          echo '### Hello world! :rocket:' >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
```

However the summary isn't displayed. Anyone else having this problem? What am I doing wrong here ?

(I'm running GHES v3.5.0, and runner v2.292.0)

For an overview of github_step_summary, see here: https://github.blog/2022-05-09-supercharging-github-actions-with-job-summaries/

Comment: What is this `$GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY`? Is it a variable that would be created by the workflow and added to the Github workflow context, or something else you would like to re-use smewhere?

Comment: An overview of github_step_summary is here: https://github.blog/2022-05-09-supercharging-github-actions-with-job-summaries/

Comment: If this is all your workflow does, consider changing the permissions to `permissions: {}`, because you don't need any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [Job Summaries](https://github.blog/2022-05-09-supercharging-github-actions-with-job-summaries/) are not yet available in GitHub Enterprise Server. Since GitHub Enterprise Server has a code freeze and testing period before its release, that feature would have missed the GHES 3.5 release.

You should expect it to be available in GHES 3.6.